# Including other certificates when signing using SignedCms and CmsSigner on .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, x509certificate2, pkcs

I'm trying to implement the following signing operation using C# .NET APIs.

`$ openssl smime -binary -sign -certfile WWDR.pem -signer signerCertWithKey.pem -in manifest.json -out signature -outform DER -passin pass:<signerKey passphrase>`
(adapter from the very last step described at https://github.com/alexandercerutti/passkit-generator/wiki/Generating-Certificates).

My code is something like (please see the comments in the code):

```
    static byte[] GetSignature(X509Certificate2 x509,
        byte[] dataToSign, IList<X509Certificate2>? certs=default)
    {

        ContentInfo contentInfo = new(dataToSign);
        SignedCms cms = new(contentInfo, true); // A detached SignedCms message.
        
        // Sign the message.
        CmsSigner cmsSigner = new(x509);
        
        if (certs != default)
        {
            foreach (var cert in certs)
            {
    /* This part is where I have doubt. What's the correct way to add the 
    additional certificates (that cert doesn't include any private key) 
    corresponding to what's specified by the "-certfile" flag of 
    the openssl command shown above?
    */
                cms.AddCertificate(cert); // <-- Should it be added like this
                // cmsSigner.Certificates.Add(cert); // <--- OR like this

                /* In both the cases I get an error complaining about the
                missing private key in the certificate.*/
            }
        }
        cms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner);

        /* Produces a CMS/PKCS #7 message containing the signature.*/
        return cms.Encode();

    }
```

Any pointer to the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Following is the complete code to help reproduce this issue.

```
    using System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

    namespace Foo.Common;

    public class FooUtil
    {

        public static byte[] GetSignature(string certPemFile,
            byte[] dataToSign, ReadOnlySpan<char> password,
            string? keyFilePath = default, IList<string>? moreCertPemFiles = default)
        {
            var x509 = X509Certificate2.CreateFromEncryptedPemFile(certPemFile,
            password, keyFilePath);

            List<X509Certificate2> certs = new(); // Holds additional certificates
            if (moreCertPemFiles != default)
            {
                foreach (var item in moreCertPemFiles)
                {
                    certs.Add(X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(item));
                }
            }

            // The dataToSign byte array holds the data to be signed.
            ContentInfo contentInfo = new(dataToSign);
            // Create a new, detached SignedCms message.
            SignedCms signedCms = new(contentInfo, true);
            if (certs != default) // Attach additional certificates
            {
                foreach (var cert in certs)
                {
                    signedCms.AddCertificate(cert);
                }
            }
            // Sign the message.
            CmsSigner cmsSigner = new(x509);
            signedCms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner);

            // Produces a CMS/PKCS #7 message containing the signature.
            return signedCms.Encode();
        }

    }
```

Unit test to run the above method:

```
    namespace Foo.Common.Tests;

    using System.Text;
    using Foo.Common;
    using NUnit.Framework;

    public class FooTests
    {

        [Test]
        public void TestSignatures()
        {
            byte[] data1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This is a test!");
            byte[] data2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This is a test!");
            byte[] data3 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Yet another test!");
            string certPem = "/home/xxx/src/mycert.pem";
            List<string> certList = new()
            {
                "/home/xxx/src/wwdr.pem"
            };
            byte[] sign1 = FooUtil.GetSignature(certPem, data1, 
                "0123456789", null, certList);
            byte[] sign2 = FooUtil.GetSignature(certPem, data2, 
                "0123456789", null, certList);
            byte[] sign3 = FooUtil.GetSignature(certPem, data3, 
                "0123456789", null, certList);
            File.WriteAllBytes("/home/xxx/sign3.p7b", sign3);

            Assert.That(sign1.Length > 10);
            Assert.That(sign2.Length > 10);
            Assert.That(sign3.Length > 10);
            Assert.That(sign1, Is.EqualTo(sign2));
            Assert.That(sign2, !Is.EqualTo(sign3));
        }

    }
```

Exception message:

```
Starting test run
[Failed] TestSignatures
    Message:
        System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException : The key contents do not contain a PEM, the content is malformed, or the key does not match the certificate.
    Stack Trace:
        at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.ExtractKeyFromPem[TAlg](ReadOnlySpan'1 keyPem, String[] labels, Func'1 factory, Func'2 import)
        at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.CreateFromPem(ReadOnlySpan'1 certPem, ReadOnlySpan'1 keyPem)
        at Foo.Common.FooUtil.GetSignature(String certPemFile, Byte[] dataToSign, ReadOnlySpan'1 password, String keyFilePath, IList'1 moreCertPemFiles) in /home/xxx/src/FooUtil.cs:line 21
        at Foo.Common.Tests.FooTests.TestSignatures() in /home/xxx/Tests/FooTest.cs:line 21
        at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
        at System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)

==== Summary ====
Failed!  - Failed:    1, Passed:    0, Skipped:    0, Total:    1, Duration: 293ms
```

Error message when using the following (as suggested by @Charlieface in comments):

```
cmsSigner.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.WholeChain;
            foreach (var cert in certs)
            {
                // signedCms.AddCertificate(cert);
                cmsSigner.Certificates.Add(cert);
            }
```

[Failed] TestSignatures
Message:
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException : The key contents do not contain a PEM, the content is malformed, or the key does not match the certificate.
Stack Trace:
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.ExtractKeyFromPem[TAlg](ReadOnlySpan'1 keyPem, String[] labels, Func'1 factory, Func'2 import)
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.CreateFromPem(ReadOnlySpan'1 certPem, ReadOnlySpan'1 keyPem)
at Foo.Common.FooUtil.GetSignature(String certPemFile, Byte[] dataToSign, ReadOnlySpan'1 password, String keyFilePath, IList'1 moreCertPemFiles)

Comment: What is the full stack trace you're getting from calling cms.AddCertificate? (or cms.ComputeSignature/Encode/whatever is throwing when you call or have called AddCertificate)?

Answer (score 0):

Seems from [the source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6072e4d3a7a2a1493f514cdf4be75a3d56580e84/src/libraries/System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs/src/System/Security/Cryptography/Pkcs/SignedCms.cs#L72) that `SignedCms.Certificates` creates a new collection every time, and this does not connect back to the `SignedCms` object.

Instead use `SignedCms.AddCertificate`.

That function was added through [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/24222), exactly why the original function was not modified instead is not clear.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Any pointers for how I can address the missing private key issue? Event when using `SignedCms.AddCertificate`, I get the following exception:
`
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException : The key contents do not contain a PEM, the content is malformed, or the key does not match the certificate.
    Stack Trace:
           at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.ExtractKeyFromPem[TAlg](ReadOnlySpan1 keyPem, String[] labels, Func1 factory, Func2 import)
           at `

Comment: Please show the full stack trace. What happens if you try instead `cmsSigner.Certificates.Add(cert);` and `cmsSigner.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.WholeChain;` in other words you change the signing object rather than the `SignedCms` envelope.